# max-height transition not working when max-height is reduced

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

If the `max-height` of a `div` is increased, the `css` transition works fine, but when the `max-height` of the same `div` is decreased, the height changes without transition.

Here's the jsfiddle of the code similar to mine.
https://jsfiddle.net/31sukrxq/43/

```css
.a {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.b {
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.c {
  max-height: 200px;
  background: slategray;
  color: white;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
}

.c:hover {
  max-height: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.c-parent {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    Background DIV
  </div>
  <div class="c-parent">
    <div class="c">
      Hover over me<br> foo bar<br> foo bar<br> foo bar<br> foo bar<br> foo bar<br> foo bar<br> foo bar<br> foo bar<br> foo bar<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's animating the height not max-height, since you don't have height set on `.c` in the normal state, so there is no transition. If you remove the height of 300 from hovered state, there is no animation at all

Comment: You need to give .c a set height in order for it to animate

Comment: @Huangism If you change `transition: 1s;` to `transition: max-height 1s;`, it would animate, not when we change it to `transition: height 1s;`. So, max-height is being animated.

Comment: @manish it only animates because you increased the height to 300px. So of course the max-height will animate due to the fact that height itself has increased but guess what, when not hovered, you didn't set a height so it doesn't animate anymore

Comment: @yerme @Huangism: I don't want to enforce height on `.c`. If the content is 150px, I just want that much height.

Comment: @manish see my answer for using min-height instead of height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without setting a height, you jsut have to set a min-height, see below example

Note - in the normal `.c` state, you could set min-height to 1px if you want but it will speed up the animation because you are going from 300 to 1

```css
.a {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.b {
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.c {
  max-height: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: slategray;
  color: white;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
}

.c:hover {
  max-height: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.c-parent {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    Background DIV
  </div>
  <div class="c-parent">
    <div class="c">
      Hover over me<br>
      foo bar<br>
      foo bar<br>
      foo bar<br>
      foo bar<br>
      foo bar<br>
      foo bar<br>
      foo bar<br>
      foo bar<br>
      foo bar<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote in the hover pseudo-class the max-height and the height.
If you use min-height instead of height, it will work, but you have to set in both blocks:

```
.c {
  max-height: 200px;
  min-height: 0px;       <=====
  background: slategray;
  color: white;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
}

.c:hover {
  max-height: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;       <=====
}
```

This shuld solve your issue.

Comment: @fernado: I don't want to enforce height on `.c`. If the content is 150px, I just want that much height.